# Get 25 % of lines of a file

Tags: shell

i try to display 25% randomly of lines of file

This is my script:

```
file=$1
nb_lignes=$(wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1)
num_lines_to_get=$((25*${nb_lignes}/100)) 
for (( i=0; i < $num_lines_to_get; i++))
do
line=$(head -$((${RANDOM} % $nb_lignes)) $file | tail -1)
echo "$line"
done
fi
```

i run like that

```
./script.sh file
```

file is:

```
xxxxxxxx-54.yyyyy
xxxxxxxx-55.yyyyy
xxxxxxxx-60.yyyyy
xxxxxxxx-66.yyyyy
```

My question please how can i eliminate 54 an 55 , i mean i'd like 25% of this list other than this two lines 54 and 55, and i'd like to specify it in the command like that

```
./script.sh file 54 55
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your example file has four lines.  If you eliminate the first two lines, you have only two.  How do you remove 25% of a list of two? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 25% of lines= 1 line in this example, i'd like this line is 60 or 66 not 54 or 55

Comment: Ah, so 25% of the original set, not 25% of what remains after you've excluded some.

Comment: A very unclear posting: elimination of 54 and 55 seems to be the whole another task than the task specified in the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to calculate 25% unless you know how many lines represent 100%, so all your solutions will either (1) be single-pass and store your file in memory, or (2) be multi-pass in order to gather the number of lines.  I don't know how long a file you're dealing with, but I prefer the second option anyway, so that's how I'l answer.

If you're running Linux, then you probably have GNU version of most tools.  One solution might be:

```
#!/bin/sh

linecount=$(awk 'END{printf("%d", NR * 0.25)}' input.txt)
exclude="$@"
egrep -vw "${exclude// /|}" input.txt | shuf -n$linecount
```

or alternately:

```
#!/bin/sh

linecount=$(awk 'END{printf("%d", NR * 0.25)}' input.txt)
exclude="$@"
egrep -vw "${exclude// /|}" input.txt | sort -R | head -n $linecount
```

This solution assumes that the "xxxxxx" and "yyyyy" strings will not contain word-delimited versions of the numbers you're trying to skip.  If they might, then you should probably give us more details, like actual sample data.

If you're using FreeBSD or OSX, then `sort` doesn't have a `-R` option and `shuf` isn't included, but you can still get this done.  You'll have a tool called `jot` in your system.  It can be used to produce random numbers within a range.  So this is a little awkward, but it works:

```
#!/bin/sh

# `awk` is a little heaver than `wc`, but you don't need to parse its output.
lines=$(awk 'END{printf("%d", NR * 0.25)}' input.txt)

exclude="$@"

# First, put a random number at the beginning of each line.
while read line; do
  # skip lines that match our exclusion list
  if [[ $line =~ -($exclude). ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  echo "`jot -r 1 1 10000000` $line"
done < input.txt > stage1.txt

# Next, sort by the random number.
sort -n stage1.txt > stage2.txt

# Last, remove the number from the start of each line.
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+ //' stage2.txt > stage3.txt

# Show our output
head -n $lines stage3.txt

# Clean up
rm stage1.txt stage2.txt stage3.txt
```

If you like, you can combine some of these lines to avoid staging things to separate files.

```
#!/bin/sh

lines=$(awk 'END{printf("%d", NR * 0.25)}' input.txt)

exclude="$@"

while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ -(${exclude// /|})\. ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  echo "`jot -r 1 1 10000000` $line"
done < input.txt | sort -n | sed -r 's/^[0-9]+ //' | head -n $lines

# no clean-up required
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collection of unix tools. `shuf` is a good one, as are `wc` and `awk`. Use the same method to count the lines, but then adjust the number of lines-to-print to ignore some lines and then print a random number of them.

```
num_lines=$(wc -l $file | cut -f1 -d' ' )
high=55
low=54

if [ "$num_lines" -ge $high ]; then : $((num_lines--)); fi
if [ "$num_lines" -ge $low ]; then : $((num_lines--)); fi

awk '(NR != '$low' && NR != '$high') { print }' < $file \
    | shuf -n $((num_lines / 4))
```

Note that the order of the if statements is important, so that the correct number of subtractions happen (i.e. if the file has 54 lines, then only one line should be skipped, so only one subtraction, and if it has 55 lines, then two lines will be skipped, and this ordering is required or the second subtraction won't happen.)

Note, if you want the lines to be in their original order then the following can be used in place of the last `awk .. | shuf ..` pipeline.

```
awk '(NR != '$low' && NR != '$high') { print NR,$0 }' < $file \
    | shuf -n $((num_lines / 4)) | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' '
```

(It first labels each line with it's line number and the sorts by this and removes it afterwards, i.e. a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).)

Comment: Where is `shuf` from?  I don't see it in FreeBSD or OSX.

Comment: @ghoti, not sure, but it's installed on my debian box by default.

Comment: @ghoti, actually, it appears to be part of the [GNU coreutils](http://man.cx/shuf).

Comment: Ah, I see.  GNU coreutils is indeed rather Linux-centric.  Also, you should consider updating your answer so the `$low` and `$high` are passed to your awk script as variables rather than substituted in by the shell.  As it stands, an invalid (or null) value for one of those would break your awk script.